# Force-run module install script in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, install-script, installdata

I have added some install data to my module (EAV attributes), and it doesn't look like it's working. However, I don't seem to get any relevant errors in the logs, and am a bit lost on whether the install script ever ran in the first place. I tried two ways to run it:

> - Disable/enable module
> - Running setup:upgrade

Is there a way to force-run just my install script? If not, does `setup:upgrade` always run it, and if so, which log should I be looking at?

Edit: Here is the relevant part of the install data script:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'some_action_timestamp', [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Some action timestamp',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'some_action_timestamp')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

    $attribute->save();
```

Comment: Have you created any install data script in any module?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by 'added some install data to my module'. I will add it to the question.

Comment: have you check your module version is going into setup_module table?

Comment: It's not going up, I thought it didn't matter for install (only for upgrade), but might be wrong. In any case, this is part of the question, is it possible to force-run the install script without changing the version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to run installation scripts for a "local" module (not installed with composer) and the module is already installed, you should:

- Remove module installation registry from database, in the `setup_module` table.
- Re-run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

This will execute installation scripts as if the module wasn't previously installed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dani I was able to resolve this.  I had a module install that went bad and I was getting:

```
Table 'magento.mgz_ninjamenus_menu' doesn't exist
```

I use docker and so here is the complete list of commands I used to help this (might help a Magento noob):

```
#view list docker container names
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"

#connect to the docker instance
docker exec -it name_of_mysql_container bash

mysql -umagento -pmagento magento

use magento;
select * from setup_module;
#find the name of the module in the displayed list

delete from setup_module where module = 'module_name_from_the_query_above';

#you should see something like:
#   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
exit
exit

#now run your own flush commands including:
#  bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

i realized there's no record in **setup_module** table (neither install script does run for your module) unless you define **setup_version** attribute into < module > element of **etc/module.xml**

/magento v2.3.5p1/